# DistributedMap feature: how to use it

Tags: websphere-liberty, open-liberty

How to use the Liberty's [distributedmap](https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/reference/feature/distributedMap-1.0.html) feature in a Java application?

Where I can find the required Maven dependencies (com.ibm.websphere.cache..)?

Answer (score 0):

The Maven dependencies for WebSphere features like the DistributedMap are defined in the https://github.com/WASdev/ci.maven.tools repository and they are published on Maven central.

The following dependency loads all APIs:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.wasdev.maven.tools.targets</groupId>
    <artifactId>liberty-apis</artifactId>
    <version>${liberty.dependency.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Maven coordinates for the distributedMap API would be:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api.distributedMap</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.68</version>
</dependency>
```

Each release of Liberty will have a different version, but that is from 22.0.0.9 the latest version as of this response. I found this by using [search.maven.org](https://search.maven.org/) and searching for `distributedMap`. This should work for other features APIs as well.